# How to use a regexp to search/match specific pattern only for the custom statusline and/or tabline?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, autocmd, statusline, syntax

I got this regexp from google which is for matching specific glyphs in vim-nerdtree.

```
autocmd FileType nerdtree syntax match {hl-group} /\v{glyph}/ containedin=ALL
```

But obviously it won't work on custom statusline/tabline. What events should I use for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:syntax` command only covers actual buffer contents. Both statusline and (terminal) tabline, though displayed with the same font and highlighting possibilities as the windows that contain buffer contents, are different: They belong to the editor UI elements.

The main reason for syntax highlighting is highlighting parts of the text with different colors or text attributes, through *highlight groups*. For the tabline, there's a fixed set of highlight groups ([`:help setting-tabline`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#setting-tabline)), for the statuslines there are two different groups for active and inactive ([`:help hl-StatusLine`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-StatusLine)). Inside both, you  can include 9 different user highlightings via the `%1*...%*` items, cp. [`:help hl-User1..9`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-User1..9).

You cannot use this for *concealing* characters, but this can be done by including a custom Vimscript expression (`%{...}`) and translating / removing the characters in there.

Comment: For the tabline, you can use the full highlighting options as for the statusline, if you use a text based tabline (e.g. `:set guioptions-=e`)

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBrabandt, I had missed that! Nice that this actually is consistent; I've adapted my answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using terminal vim

Comment: @JohnFredFadrigalan: That's already considered by the answer.